# Bokeh code to open pop up window showing data table on button click

Tags: pandas-bokeh

I am developing a web application using bokeh. My requirement is to open pop up window on button click. The pop up window should display a data table widget. Secondly, This pop up window is draggable. Since my application is web based so cannot use pyqt. Is there any way to achieve this?